# How to convert to date format (dd-mm-yyyy) from datepicker to sqlserver?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I am working on a project where i can fetch the date from front end using datepicker and store it in sql server in dd-mm-yyyy format. I have used the following code to store. but it didn't work where it stores in datepicker format only. Can anyone help me out to reach this? Thanks in advance.

Here's the function which i used:
convert(varchar(50),@dob,105)

note: @dob is a scalar variable which i get this value from stored procedure.

Comment: convert it to datetime

Comment: Why are you storing it in SQL Server as *text* at all? It would be a much better idea to make your database column a `Date` column, at which point your interaction with it should be via `DateTime` rather than strings.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 0):

The string format that Sql Server understands for a date is this one 'yyyy-mm-dd'

so pass your variable as e.g.: '2014-12-10' and you should be fine

Comment: While this will work, it's still not a good idea. Avoid string conversions as far as possible - use the most appropriate type for the job, which in this case is something like `DateTime`.

Comment: I totally agree that you should use DateTime in this case, but we do not know if this applies to his problem (might be some legacy code or something)

Comment: Well if the field isn't a `Date` or `DateTime` field in the database, then how SQL Server interprets dates is irrelevant, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be converting the string into DateTime value in front end. Hope your database and application server are in same region (Then you dont have the culture issue. Else you can use CultureInfo for converting the DateTime).

Comment: Hi, Yeah I have changed region too. But it doesn't work. It displays in the same datepicker format as: "Dec 10 2014 4:30PM"

Answer (score 0):

You could change the culture of your website. Then automaticly the dateformat will be normalized for the specific country. In this case your datetimeformat is the same as the Netherlands.

Add this for your country in your web.config

```
<globalization culture="nl-NL" uiCulture="nl-NL" />
```

This will not change the way the date is stored but you do not have to change the dateformat every time when obtaining or saving a datetime.